# Stack Overflow Logging In

Tags: discussion, login

I have StackOverflow account A.

Then, in another browser, I accidentally created new account B.  I realized, I dont need new account, so I deleted account B from Profile/Settings area.

Now, I would like to log into StackOverflow using my existing account A but on the same browser where I created (and deleted) account B, StackOverflow shows only option to "Join" which then shows only option to "Confirm And Create This Account" as shown below
[image]

But there is no option to just log in which is what I want.
If I open another browser, I can log in using my account A

Comment: Maybe if you clear your cache/history/cookie? and be sure to be at the home page of stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Go to the StackExchange main page and log out there.

Answer (score 1):

First off make sure you clear your history and cache. Then restart your browser and see if that fixes the issue. That should fix the problem, if not then make sure to check your email to make sure that Stack Overflow has officially deleted the account (should get a confirmation email of sorts).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  You have to go to menu in top left and log out there even tough you deleted your account:

[image]